# How to switch between the windows of the same application on SL?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, alt-tab, switch

I'm trying to get a grip of OS X (SL), but haven't yet found a keyboard shortcut to switch windows of a single application, say, Safari. I can hit <kbd>F10</kbd> and select the right window from there but it feels unnecessarily complicated - and needs a mouse.

So, is there a shortcut to switch windows of a single application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal shortcuts for switching between windows of the same application are:

Cmd + `

Cmd + ~

In some applications, Terminal for example, also Cmd + [left|right] works, but the standard way (and also the more common one) is by using ` and ~.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In case it is not obvious, the key for ` is to the left of the "1" key on US Mac keyboards. (Or at least it is on my keyboard).

Comment: Right. My mistake. I was talking about the key next to the Z.

Comment: Ok, things get interesting with Dvorak layout...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you are using OS X Exposé to [switch between the windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expos%C3%A9_%28Mac_OS_X%29).

You can also activate Exposé with the mouse. Go into System Preferences and select the preferences for Exposé. Then configure one of the "Active Screen Corners" to enable the Exposé function you want. After you do this moving the mouse cursor to the corner of the screen you enabled will accomplish the same thing as pressing F10 currently does for you.

Note that you can also use an active corner to enable spaces. (If you completely lose track of a windows activating both spaces and Exposé at the same time can be one way to find it quickly. ;-)

FWIW, in the case of Safari another possibility is simply to do more of your browsing using "tabs". Or to use the `Window` -> `Merge All Windows` Safari menu item.

Comment: I do use tabs, but every now and then some links open into a new window. I also try not to use mouse, but Active Corners may benefit other readers.

Comment: @Jawa: Sorry. I interpreted your observation "and needs a mouse" in your question to mean you were looking for a way to use your mouse. I now see it as an expression of your distaste for the requirement to use the mouse as part of the Exposé window selection process.